# invalid qualifier / decimals issue

Tags: excel, vba

I want to clear the cells that contain the max and min value on some data:

```
Sub Macro5()
Dim vmax, vmin, lmax, lmin As Double
Set rango = Range("DA200:WB300")
Set vamx = rango.Find(Application.WorksheetFunction.max(rango),LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
Set vmin = rango.Find(Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(rango),LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not vmax Is Nothing Then
    lmax = vmax.ClearContents
End If
If Not vmin Is Nothing Then
    lmin = vmin.ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

But the code doesn´t work.

Tip: When I use numbers without decimals, it works fine. But when I change them for the real ones (like 0.565807486680781), the code stop working.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will want to Dim your variables like this instead `Dim vmax As Double, vmin As Double, lmax As Double, lmin As Double` if you want them all to be doubles. Otherwise, they will be variants. This may or may not help your issue.

Comment: what do you think is happening with this line `lmax = vmax.ClearContents`

Comment: you also have a typo here `Set vamx `

Comment: What do you mean by `stop working`?  How are you entering the `real numbers`?  You never declare `vamax`.  `vmax` will never be anything prior to you testing it. `vmax, vmin, lmax` have all been declared as Variant type. In `Tools/Options` set to Require variable declaration.  In your current code, enter `Option Explicit` at the very beginning.  Then you may start to see where your problems are.